# Can't get dynamic Gutenberg block to render on the frontend

Tags: block-editor

I tried everything I found online. The backend appears, including dynamic segments (withSelect, etc). But the simplest 'render-callback' doesn't appear on the frontend.

plugin.php

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: My Dynamic Block
 */

function my_plugin_render_dynamic_block( ) {
    return '<h1>Sample Block</h1>';
}

function register_dynamic_block() {
    wp_register_script(
        'dynamic-block',
        plugins_url( '/dist/block.js ', __FILE__),
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-element', 'wp-editor' ),
        filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'dist/block.js' )
    );

    register_block_type(
        'my-plugin/dynamic-block',
        [
            'editor_script' => 'dynamic-block',
            'render_callback' => 'my_plugin_render_dynamic_block',
        ]
    );
}
add_action('init', 'register_dynamic_block');
```

block.js

```
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;

registerBlockType( 'my-plugin/dynamic-block', {
    title: 'My Dynamic Block',
    icon: 'megaphone',
    category: 'widgets',

    edit({attributes}) {
        return (
            <div>Content</div>
        );
    },

    save() {
        return null;
    },
} );
```

Comment: Your save function is returning `null` https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg-examples/blob/7b30f31ff4dfe23997313e5269b483796f166b7f/01-basic/block.js#L30 I think it has to return something.

Comment: I just tested the code and it works as expected. The only difference in what I tried is adding the js in a script enqueued in the `enqueue_block_editor_assets` action which, might be the issue?

Comment: Returning null is correct on a Dynamic Block as the rendering is handled by PHP

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score -2):

Since you're making a dynamic block you don't need to register the block in JavaScript. Take a look at the Latest Posts block in Core to see how they do it.

Answer (score -3):

Even if you do manage to render frontend with null return, On the next page reload you'll get block validation error. Because your html structure on edit function will not be matching up with save function. So

Instead of

```
    save() {
        return null;
    },
```

Try

```
     save() {
         return (
           <div>Content</div>
       );
    },
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The return null is specifically implemented to ignore validation errors and fallback to server side rendering using the render_callback attribute.